# How to read multiple nltk corpus files and write in a single text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, corpus

I have written the following code:

```
import nltk
```

then

```
file1 = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('shakespeare-caesar.txt')
file2 = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('shakespeare-hamlet.txt')
file3 = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('shakespeare-macbeth.txt')
```

the part where I try to write the contents in a single file

```
filenames = [file1, file2, file3]
with open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile: #want to store the contents of 3 files in result.txt
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

for which i get the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-917545c3c1ce> in <module>()
      2 with open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile:
      3     for fname in filenames:
----> 4         with open(fname) as infile:
      5             for line in infile:
      6                 outfile.write(line)

TypeError: invalid file: ['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Julius', 'Caesar', ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the last line in the error message shows, `file1` et al. are not filenames, but lists of words. Instead of using the words function, you can just combine the files into one like this:

```
filenames = [
    "shakespeare-caesar.txt",
    "shakespeare-hamlet.txt",
    "shakespeare-macbeth.txt"
]
with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in filenames:
        f.write(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw(filename))
```

Comment: any idea why it doesn't work on the following piece of code:
_files = ["firefox.txt",
 "grail.txt",
 "overheard.txt",
 "pirates.txt",
 "singles.txt",
 "wine.txt"]       
with open("merge.txt", "w") as f:
    for file in files:
        f.write(nltk.corpus.webtext.raw(file))_

I am getting the following error:

      7 with open("merge.txt", "w") as f:
      8     for file in files:
----> 9         f.write(nltk.corpus.webtext.raw(file))

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x99' in position 95156: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Mitesh, are you sure you are using Python 3?

Comment: @alexis yes python 3.5

Comment: Tell it what encoding you want to use for the merged file: `open("merge.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")`.